# android java sdk, loading bookmarks into spinner?

Tags: java, android, sdk, spinner, bookmarks

The spinner comes up with but with nothing in it

what am I doning wrong?

```
cbookmarks = Browser.getAllBookmarks(getContentResolver());
SimpleCursorAdapter ABM = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cbookmarks,new String[] {android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL},new int[]{R.id.Spinner});
ABM.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
SpinnerBM.setAdapter(ABM);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `R.id.Spinner` a `TextView`?  Perhaps you can post the XML you have defined for the layout of the entries?

**UPDATE**
According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) the array of id's that you pass into the `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor need to be `TextView`.  Most examples I have seen use the built-in id of `android.R.id.text1`, but I think you can define your own custom layouts too.

Comment: It's a spinner. <Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner"
 android:layout_width="300px" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </Spinner>

Comment: I'm revisiting this code after a few months away from it.. but do think I'm off. I would think I'm need to first load URLs from android.provider.Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL to the adapter and then bind the adapter to the spinner. The ids are not coming from a textview, but rather URLs from my bookmarks.  If anybody has any sample code that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you! that was actually it. I have another related entry.. working on this thing every 6 months apparently.. whree now I can't seem to get the selected value. Thanks.